# Php Implode Not Working with my code

Tags: php

i have an array and i want to convert this array in comma seprated string by implode function but this is not working. my code is below.

```
<?php foreach ($article['hashtags'] as $hashtags) { ?>
   <?php $hastagg=mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$hashtags)) ?>
   <a><?php echo $hastagg; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What is it doing and what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on something you're outputting to the browser?

Comment: How does your array look? Is it an array of arrays or not? Because if it isn't, you shouldn't do the implode inside a foreach. Check out the manual of implode to see what parameters it needs. also, show your array here. And last: what does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Does you computer burst into flames when you attempt to execute it? Seriously, if you could give an example of the output, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<?php 
    $hastagg = htmlentities(implode(',' ,$article['hashtags'])) ;
    echo '<a>'.$hastagg.'</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about structure of `$article` array. But I have a feeling that `foreach` is unnecessary:

```
$hashtagg = implode(',', $article['hashtags']);
```

And why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` for output? You can use htmlspecialchars or some other functions.